# efficient with or in?

Tags: prepositional-phrases

I wonder if the following sentences make sense or have any difference:

1. I am more efficient with single-tasking than multi-tasking.
2. I am more efficient in single-tasking than multi-tasking.
3. I work more efficiently with single-tasking than multi-tasking

Which one actually is better? Thanks!

Comment: When is better. I am more efficient when single-tasking than when multi-tasking.

Comment: At least in British English, *at* would be preferred. (Or *when* as suggested above, although I would suggest this changes the meaning slightly, to focus more on the internal constitution of the activity.)